# react-dropzone convert uploaded file to a byte array

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-dropzone

I have the following code, I would like to take the uploaded file and pass it through to an api as a Byte array, is this possible?

```
    interface IData{
        file: Uint8Array
    }
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    <div>
                        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
                            Add Data
                                            </Button>
                        <DropzoneDialog
                            acceptedFiles={['image/*']}
                            cancelButtonText={"cancel"}
                            submitButtonText={"submit"}
                            maxFileSize={5000000}
                            open={open}
                            onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
                            onSave={(files) => {
                                let data = {} as IData;
                                data.file = files[0];
// Call api here... but
                            setOpen(false);
                        }}
                        showPreviews={true}
                        showFileNamesInPreview={true}
                    />
```

but on the line `data.file = files[0]` I get the following error

> `Type 'File' is missing the following properties from type 'Uint8Array': BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, buffer, byteLength, byteOffset, and 25 more.ts(2740)`

What is the the best way to get the uploaded file as a byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) with [`readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) to convert the file object to a byte array

```
onSave={(files) => {

     const reader = new FileReader();
     reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
         let data = {} as IData;
         data.file = new Uint8Array(reader.result as ArrayBuffer);
        // call api here 
        setOpen(false);
     });
     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
}
```

Comment: thanks!!!  I get a compile time error on reader.result  Overload 1 of 5, '(elements: Iterable<number>): Uint8Array', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<number>'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<number>'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(length: number): Uint8Array', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Overload 3 of 5, '(arrayOrArrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer

Comment: Could you try `new Uint8Array(reader.result as ArrayBuffer)` in the above code